# docker permission denied

Tags: docker

```
docker pull sundowndev/phoneinfoga:latest
```

That's what I tried in Terminal. I got error

```
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=sundowndev%2Fphoneinfoga&tag=latest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I am new to docker. So, I don't know what's happening After searching little I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue) and [this](https://linuxhandbook.com/docker-permission-denied/). But, I didn't understand anything.

I was trying [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/permission-denied-var-run-docker-sock-when-running-docker-in-docker) and [this](https://www.geekpills.com/operating-system/linux/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket)

In this [link](https://www.geekpills.com/operating-system/linux/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket), I was unable to understand `sudo usermod  -aG  docker ssirohi`. I didn't understand that. that's why I tried `sudo usermod  -aG  docker Istiakshovon` I got the error `usermod: group 'docker' does not exist` . Should I install docker group? How to do that? I have docker... I tried [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957722/13146129) also.

Comment: Are you a member of `docker` group?

Comment: And if you are a member of the docker group, did you log out and back in after becoming a member of that group?

Comment: Check the permissions of the socket. Depending on setup, you need to be part of the `docker` group, or sometimes `root` directly.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk No!

Comment: I have created docker account. I have login from terminal also. While I was login I got the error `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/auth: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
`

Comment: @Panki I have created the `docker` by `snap install docker`. There's no desktop entry of it. And, I am unable to get socket in https://hub.docker.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying as [he said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957722/13146129), I reboot later since then docker is working...

```
$ sudo groupadd docker

$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

$ newgrp docker

$ docker run hello-world

$ sudo reboot now
```